# Post print dictionary/json returns error to client

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, marmalade

I am sending post request in the body of some json data, to process on server and I want the results back to client(c++ app on phone) in the form of json data and hence parse on mobile.
I have the following code inside handler:

```
class ServerHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
        id = data.get('id',None)
        #process data from db (take a while) and pack in result which is dictinary
        result = process_data(id)# returns dictionary from db= takes time
        print 'END OF HANDLER'
        print json.dumps(result)

        #before this code below I have tried also
        #return result
        #return self.write(result)
        #return self.write(json.dumps(result)) 
        #return json.dumps(result)
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        json_ = tornado.escape.json_encode(result)
        self.write(json_)
        self.finish()
        #return json.dumps(result)
```

I always get printed `'END OF HANDLER'` and `valid dictinary/json` below on console but when I read at client mobile I always get

```
<html><title>405: Method Not Allowed</title><body>405: Method Not Allowed</body></html>
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the bug ?
(I am using CIwGameHttpRequest for sending request and it works when file is static =>name.json but now same content is giving error in post request. )

Comment: Try to use CIwHTTP instead of CIwGameHttpRequest. If it also doesn't work then you're calling the wrong method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error (HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed) means that you have made a request to a valid URL, but you are using an HTTP verb (e.g. `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) that cannot be used with that URL.

Your web service code appears to handle the `POST` verb, as evidenced by the `post` method name, and also by the fact that incoming requests appear to have a request body.  You haven't shown us your C++ client code, so all I can do is to speculate that it is making a `GET` request.  Does your C++ code call `Request->setPOST();`?  (I haven't worked with `CIwGameHttpRequest` before, but Googling for it I found [this page](http://www.appeasymobile.com/forum/reports-bugs/339-post-issue) from which I took that line of code.)

I've not worked with Tornado before, but I imagine that there is some mechanism somewhere that allows you to connect a URL to a `RequestHandler`.  Given that you have a 405 Method Not Allowed error rather than 404 Not Found, it seems that however this is done you've done it correctly.  You issue a `GET` request to Tornado for the URL, it determines that it should call your handler, and only when it tries to use your handler it realises that it can't handle `GET` requests, concludes that your handler (and hence its URL) doesn't support `GET`s and returns a 405 error.